# Find one date format in file and replace with another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have about 5000 text files that have a date stored in a format of YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z and would like to change this format to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM.

I have the advantage in knowing each date format is preceded by the string `Closed:`.

I've been using the following to change the date format which seems to work:

```
def datePrettyPrint(date):
    d = dateutil.parser.parse(date)
    return(d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'))
```

So far, I have the following:

```
import fileinput, os

directory = "/home/ubuntu/workspace/files/"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file :
        filedata = file.read()

    filedata = filedata.replace('Closed: FORMAT1', 'Closed: FORMAT2')

    with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
```

What I don't know is how to take `FORMAT1` and change it to `FORMAT2`. I hope I'm close here.

Edit: Example of text in the file

```
Subject: Random Text
Author: Some Name
Closed: 2014-11-21T17:39:43.000Z

Here is a message with more text
```

It's the 3rd line I'm trying to find and replace.

Comment: You have to (1) grep the `date_value` out --> (2) call `datePrettyPrint(date_value)` to get `new_date_value` --> (3) `filedata.replace(data_value, old_value)`. Regard step(1), maybe use regex to help. Btw could you provide your source file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression. There are libraries of patterns on the web or you can write your own. The python portion is pretty straight forward, something along the lines of:

```
import re
import datetime
for match in re.findall(mySearchPattern, textToSearch)
    #convert match to new format
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(match, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m:%s.000Z")
    dateNewFormat = datetime_object.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
    #substitute the old date with the new
    re.sub(match, dateNewFormat, textToSearch)
```

Comment: I haven't done too much with regex, but if I'm understanding this correctly, I'd be using the regex to only look for the date format that I want to change?

Comment: The regular expression is a search pattern that needs to match the dates you want to replace.

Comment: Here is a regex that validates the YYYY-MM-DDT portion: https://regex101.com/r/mOBRJP/1